# Parsing array syntax using regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I found the answer for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22730661/parsing-array-syntax-using-regex) but it's in php.

I would like to match an array like `[123, "hehe", "lala"]` but only if the array syntax is correct.

I made this regex  `/\["?.+"?(?:,"?.+"?)*\]/`.

The problem is that if the input is `[123, "hehe, "lala"]`, the regex match, but the syntax is incorrect.

How can I make it only match if the array syntax is correct?

My problem is making the second `"` required when the first `"`is matched.

Edit: I'm only trying to do it only with strings and numbers inside the array.

Comment: What about arrays inside of arrays? Do you need to handle those? Or just arrays of strings and numbers?

Comment: Your `.+` do not restrict much, only line breaks. Also, you are missing anchors, `^` and `$`, on both sides. Note that you need to make sure you support escape sequences, too. It is hardly a job for a regex in the end, though possible.

Comment: @RayToal Only numbers and strings

Comment: What about escaped strings eg.. `["John said \"Hello\".", 4,5,6]`

Comment: I haven't think about escaped strings, but it's possible and a good thing to consider

Comment: `JSON.parse` does that.

Comment: @str  It's what I was just about to suggest.. :)  `try { JSON.parse('["one", 1,2]'); console.log("valid"); } catch(e) { console.log("invalid"); }`

Comment: But I want to match an array syntax in a string, my input isn't a stringfied object

Comment: JSON is a string,..  What do you mean stringfied json?

Comment: sorry by the mistake

Comment: You [won't like it](https://regex101.com/r/NZJzlX/1): `/^\[\s*(?:\d+|"[^"\\]*(?:\\[^][^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\[^][^'\\]*)*')(?:\s*,\s*(?:\d+|"[^"\\]*(?:\\[^][^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\[^][^'\\]*)*'))*\s*]$/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this regex: `/\[((\d+|"([^"]|\\")*?")\s*,?\s*)*(?<!,)\]/`

Each item should either

`"([^"]|\\")*?"`: start and end with ", containing anything but ". If " is contained it should be escaped (\").

`\d+`: a number

After each item should be

`\s*,?\s*`: a comma with any number of spaces before or after.

And before the closing bracket should not be a comma: `(?<!,)`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/jRAQUc/1

Answer (score 1):

You must have two (or more) separate expressions (using the `|` operator) in order to do that.

So it would be something like this:

```
/\[\s*("[^"]*"|[0-9]+)(\s*,\s*("[^"]*"|[0-9]+))*\s*\]/
```

*(You may also want to use `^` at the start and `$` at the end to make sure nothing else appears before/after the array: `/^...snip...$/` to match the string from start to finish.)*

If you need floating point numbers with exponents, add a period and the 'e' character: `[0-9.eE]+` (which is why I did not use `\d+` because only digits are allowed in that case.) To make sure a number is valid, it's much more complicated, obviously (sign, exponent with/without sign, digits only before or after the decimal point...)

You could also support single quoted strings. That too is a separate expression: `'[^']*'`.

You may want to allow spaces before and after the brackets too (start: `/^\s*\[...` and end: `...\]\s*$/`).

Finally, if you want to really support JavaScript strings you would need to add support for the backslash. Something like this: `("([^"]|\\.)*")`.

**Note**

Your `.+` expression would match `"` and `,` too and without the `^` and `$` an array as follow matches your expression just fine:

```
This Array ["test", 123, true, "this"] Here
```